# 17:42:55.7385459 how to make this date format in java

Tags: java, date, format

2013-11-20T17:42:55.7385459
how to make this date format in java

I don't know that means, what are the last 7 characters..
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.7385459

Comment: Thats just the date and time in nanoseconds

Comment: But `Date` does not have enough precision for that output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) at the `System.nanoTime();` call, it provides precision to the nanosecond level (but not necessarily nanosecond level accuracy). **WARNING** As an example you could try (but it's probably a bad idea anyway since `nanoTime()` isn't for getting wall clock time) -

```
// It would probably be a better idea to use HH:mm:ss.SSS, and the nanoseconds.
// Not to imply that that's a good idea, just better then this (but would add even more digits).
private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
// This isn't really nanosecond accurate, and is probably a bad idea.
private static String getNanoTime() {
  long start = System.nanoTime();
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  sb.append(sdf.format(c.getTime()));
  sb.append(".");
  sb.append(System.nanoTime() - start);
  return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(getNanoTime());
}
```

Comment: @osnium76 added a bit of an explanation in code. it works on my system anyway.

Comment: System.nanoTime() - start; Didn't understand This line.. what does mean?.. Thanks anyway!

Comment: At the beginning of the `getNanoTime()` method I got the relative number of nanoseconds with the line `long start = System.nanoTime();`. To use `nanoTime()` you need to **measure time**, it doesn't return a complete time value.

Comment: Sounds very helpful.. Thank you for the answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8, the new [JSR 310: Date and Time API](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) does indeed support nanosecond precision (though your computer's clock may not).

Note the formatting code of `n`, to show `nano-of-second` as a nine-digit number such as `987654321` in [DateTimeFormatter](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). See also [ZonedDateTime](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) and [LocalDateTime](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

In contrast, the older frameworks java.util.Date/Calendar and [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) have millisecond resolution.